# Output in Sentence Form Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I want this output to be in string format.
How can it be done?

Output I am getting:

```
[[[[a]|fat]|man],[[[[[was]|walking]|quickly],to],[[[[the]]|end],[of,[[[the]|long]|corridor]]]]]
```

Expected Output:

```
a fat man was walking quickly to the end of the long corridor
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is the problem? Are you constructing this data structure? If so, maybe something with your list construction went wrong.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is solved. Yes I am generating this data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`flatten/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=flatten/2)  and [`atomic_list_concat/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atomic_list_concat/3):

```
:- X = [[[[a]|fat]|man],[[[[[was]|walking]|quickly],to],[[[[the]]|end],[of,[[[the]|long]|corridor]]]]],
   flatten(X,Y),
   atomic_list_concat(Y,' ',Z).
X = [[[[a]|fat]|man], [[[[[was]|walking]|quickly], to], [[[[the]]|end], [of, [[...|...]|...]]]]],
Y = [a, fat, man, was, walking, quickly, to, the, end|...],
Z = 'a fat man was walking quickly to the end of the long corridor'.
```

Comment: Thank You so much. I am a beginner. This helped me solve a great deal of problem for the expected output. Thank You again.